# Git запушить коммит из новой ветки в старую

Tags: git, github

Была одна ветка, master. Последний коммит в этой ветке на гитхабе был не очень, поэтому я создал новую ветку (second) на основе предыдущего коммита Master. Теперь мне нужно сохранить изменения, которые я сделал во второй ветке (second), и слить в ветку master, перезаписав все файлы на ней. Как это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иллюстрация — огонь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Если репозиторий на GitHub только ваш и больше никто им не пользуется

И если вы точно хотите отбросить изменения из последнего коммита, который «не очень».

Можно «переставить» ветку `master` на тот же коммит, на который смотрит `second`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard second
```

А потом отправить изменения на GitHub.

```
git push -f origin master
```

Последний коммит, который «не очень», останется в репозитории на некоторое время и будет доступен через `git reflog`, после чего будет удалён насовсем.

## Если репозиторий не только ваш

Тогда переписывать ветку `master` нельзя.
Будем откатывать нежелательный коммит с помощью `git revert`.

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD
```

В ветке `master` появится новый коммит, отменяющий изменения, которые внесены в нежелательном.
В результате состояние файлов будет как в коммите, где ветки разошлись.

Теперь можно перенести результат из ветки second.

```
git merge second
```

## Почему нельзя просто замержить?

Потому что изменения из нежелательного коммита никуда не денутся.
Их нужно явным образом откатить.